# Spinnaker create Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, spinnaker

I have an EC2 running in a vpc on aws. The AMI is Spinnaker-Ubuntu-14.04-43 (ami-21a26d41). This has an IAM role with: (1) AmazonEC2FullAccess, (2) AmazonS3FullAccess, (3) PowerUserAccess, (4) a policy with s3:* to my s3 bucket, sts:AssumeRole to role/SpinnakerManaged, and (5) iam:PassRole to role/BaseIAMRole.

I installed halyard on this EC2.

I enabled aws and provided it with access key and secret. Enabled S3 persistent storage and provided it the name of my S3 bucket.

SSH tunnel to this EC2, pull up Spinnaker GUI on localhost:9000 and I can see existing load balancers and security groups in the VPC.

When I tried to create a new application, I am getting an error: "Could not create application: Configured storage service does not support application permissions."

I looked at the logs in /opt/spinnaker/logs and saw that:

(1) com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.applications.tasks.UpsertApplicationTask.performRequest(UpsertApplicationTask.groovy:62)

(2) com.netflix.spinnaker.front50.controllers.PermissionsController.applicationPermissionDAO(PermissionsController.groovy:138) ~[front50-web-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]

caused by

com.netflix.spinnaker.kork.exceptions.SystemException: Configured storage service does not support application permissions

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That version of local debian is a bit too dated. I would suggest minnaker [Minnaker All in one](https://github.com/armory/mini-spinnaker)

- remember that you also need to port forward 8084 [Spinnaker Aachitecture](https://github.com/armory/mini-spinnaker)https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/architecture/
- what is halyard version `hal -v`
- what is the output of the storage config `hal config storage`
- what do you get out of `aws s3 ls`?
- also what is you `hal config`

My suggestion would be to use an All in one Spinnaker option or install in a K8S cluster. I tried Local Debian install with ubuntu 18.04 and it has issues.

I hope this helps.